# Copy files from Ftp to local directory using batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, ftp

I try to copy a lot o file from my ftp = ftp://ftp.prodega.ch so:

I created a code.txt file with this text:

```
open ftp://ftp.prodega.ch
user
password
lcd /D "E:\f2\" //this is my local directory
cd Bilder1/     //this is ftp folder
mget *
pause
```

the I execute in cmd this row : ftp -s:code.txt but I meet with this error:
unknown host: ftp://ftp.prodega.ch
help me please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When connecting to a server via the built-in FTP client you have to skip `ftp://`!

So `open ftp.prodega.ch` will fix your issue.

However, you might still face another problem. The standard FTP client doesn't support passive mode which is required by most of the servers. If you are not able to modify the server, you won't be able to download the files. You should consider using a PowerShell script instead or use a different FTP client with command line support.

Comment: thank you a lot, this helped me to solve the first problem. the second, I want to know if ftp folder location and local folder location are corect writed, thank you

Comment: If you have a new question please create a new post or modify this one and provide more information about your problem.